# Scroll to end of FlatList with contentContainerStyle

Tags: react-native

Like the title said, I have a FlatList with `contentContainerStyle` to create some space at the bottom of the list. As I tried to use `scrollToEnd()`, the list didn't seem to scroll to the bottom, in this case is the end of that extra space created by `contentContainerStyle`. Is there any way I can do to make the list auto scroll to the very end ? As of now, `scrollToEnd()` only scroll to somewhere near the end item on my list but not the very end

```
<FlatList
 {..}
 contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom:500}}
 {..}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I come up with an idea to write a scroll function take in the content height and scroll height to scroll when this height changed.

```
scrollToBottom() {
    const pointToScroll = this.contentHeight - this.scrollViewHeight;
    const scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
    scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo({x: 0, y: pointToScroll, true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using "scrollToIndex()" and pass on the last index in your flatlist.
see here for docs on the method: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

for example you could do following:

```
flatList1.scrollToIndex({
   animated: false,
   index: this.state.flastListData.length
});
```